# C# WinAPI Clicking on menu items

Tags: c#, winapi, menu, automation

I'm trying to click on a menu item inside a program called Media Subtitler and whatever I'm trying to do it's not working.

First, I tried to use the function GetMenu but it returned IntPtr.Zero.
Then, I tried using the ALT key + using the first letter of my menu (F stands for file) but it did nothing.
Then, I tried using a simple MOUSEDOWN and MOUSEUP messages but again, it did nothing (I also tried creating a loop that clicks on everything in that range but there was no click in that area).

What I clearly know is that I'm working on the correct window.

What am I doing wrong?

If someone wants to test it out you can download Media Subtitler for free and it doesn't weight that much.

Also, Here's the code I've been testing:

```
Process p = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\DivXLand\Media Subtitler\MediaSub.exe");
        p.WaitForInputIdle(1500);
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);
        ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, SW_MAXIMIZE);

        IntPtr handle = p.MainWindowHandle;

        SendMessage(handle, WM_NCHITTEST, 0, MakeLParam(18, 29));

        //for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        //{
        //    for (int x = 0; x < 200; x++)
        //    {
        //        SendMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, MakeLParam(i, x));
        //        SendMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, MakeLParam(i, x));
        //    }
        //}
        //IntPtr menuItems = GetMenu(p.MainWindowHandle);
        return;
        //SendMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, WM_COMMAND, 6, 0);
        SendMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_MENU, 0);
        SendMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYUP, VK_MENU, 0);
        SendMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F, 0);
        SendMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYUP, VK_F, 0);
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By monitoring the messages sent to the main window of the application, I extracted the menu identifiers for the menu items. You can post `WM_COMMAND` message to the window, with the ID of the menu items as the `wParam`:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Message msg, int wParam, int lParam);

PostMessage(handle, WM_COMMAND, 2, 0); // File->New subtitle

PostMessage(handle, WM_COMMAND, 3, 0); // File->New from clipboard

PostMessage(handle, WM_COMMAND, 5, 0); // File->Open text or subtitle

PostMessage(handle, WM_COMMAND, 6, 0); // File->Open video

...
```

I've tested the code with Media Subtitler, and it works like a charm! The only situation that this will not work, is when on windows Vista or Seven, your target program is running as Administrator and you C# program is not. Be aware of that!

The menu IDs can be easily examined by monitoring the `WM_COMMAND` message (using Spy++).
You can also use `SendMessage` instead of `PostMessage`, but then your program freezes until the user closes the window opened by the menu action.

You can use the same approach to send other command to other windows of the application. For example, clicking the 'Open' button of the 'Open video' window.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I looked at the program with spy++ I couldn't see the menu handler, How did you find it? Can you also write the code for getting the menu handler? Thanks.

Comment: There is no need to get the menu handler (although it available in the Properties of the window in spy++). I just monitored the messages for the window. Refresh the window list in spy++, click the `Find Window` tool and drag the cross-hair to the your window. When you found it, right click on it and select `Messages`. In this window spy++ shows all the messages are sent and posted to the window. You can filter messages by selecting `Logging options` from the `Messages` menu (Ctrl+O).

Comment: I have another small problem with another related program: I can't check the checkbox in AviReComp program in the Additions tab and in the Subtitles zone. The checkbox there is called Enable/Disable.

Comment: Can you check another checkboxes? Please post another question for this.

Comment: Sure. Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411785/unable-to-check-a-checkbox-using-c-sharp-winapi

Answer (score 5):

You can also do all of this using the System.Windows.Automation namespace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590934.aspx

Using this namespace, you do not need to do any interop with the Win32 API. Here's an example of how to get a window by searching for a string that its name contains:

```
public static AutomationElement GetWindowByName(string name)
{
    AutomationElement root = AutomationElement.RootElement;
    foreach (AutomationElement window in root.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Window)))
    {
        if (window.Current.Name.Contains(name) && window.Current.IsKeyboardFocusable)
        {
            return window;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

After you have the window as an AutomationElement object, you can search it for controls and perform operations on those controls, etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great tip, but do notice, this namespace is only relevant to _WPF_ Windows

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio there is a tool Spy++ with which you should be able to see handle of objects.
If you see it there, you should be able to get to it using user32.dll function

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string className, string lpszWindow);
```

to get to them(handle will be different everytime you run your app)
If you get the right handle, you should be able to use SendMessage to send enter, or click.

Tried this only on one app, and I used it only to read and write text, so sorry if it wont work

Comment: Another usefull tool is if you have the [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8279) use Insptect Objects (Or UISpy as it was called in older versions) to see the relationships between the windows. Very useful for when writing automation code.