# Unable to check a checkbox using C# WinAPI

Tags: c#, winapi, checkbox, automation

I'm trying to check a checkbox inside a program called AviReComp and I'm unable to do it somehow. I've tried all sorts of code:

```
//Check the checkbox
        IntPtr SubtitlesSection = FindWindowEx(MoreOptions, IntPtr.Zero, null, "Subtitles");
        IntPtr AddSubtitlesCheckbox = FindWindowEx(SubtitlesSection, IntPtr.Zero, null, "Enable/Disable");

        SendMessage(AddSubtitlesCheckbox, BM_SETSTATE, 1, IntPtr.Zero);
        SendMessage(AddSubtitlesCheckbox, BM_SETCHECK, 1, IntPtr.Zero);
        SendMessage(AddSubtitlesCheckbox, WM_PAINT, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        SendMessage(AddSubtitlesCheckbox, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 1, MakeLParam(10, 10));
        SendMessage(SubtitlesSection, WM_PARENTNOTIFY, (int)MakeLParam((int)AddSubtitlesCheckbox, WM_LBUTTONDOWN), MakeLParam(26, 31));
        SendMessage(SubtitlesSection, WM_PARENTNOTIFY, (int)MakeLParam((int)AddSubtitlesCheckbox, WM_LBUTTONUP), MakeLParam(26, 31));
```

The checkbox is located within the Additions tab underneath the Subtitles section and is called Enable/Disable.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for any help!

**Edit:** I now see that this code actually works and it does check the checkbox but I still have a problem since it does not change all the controls that are supposed to change when I check the checkbox manually and not inside my program. Is there a way to force the parent control to repaint itself or trigger the change event when I mark the checkbox as checked?

Comment: Add some errorhandling and messages to see where exactly it fails (and why).

Comment: It doesn't produce an error, it simply doesn't check the checkbox.

Comment: It is up to you to produce an error when you use the winapi.  Throw an exception when the IntPtr is IntPtr.Zero.  It very likely is.

Comment: It's not zero.  This code gets the handlers everytime.

Answer (score 0):

try to use spy++ to make sure of the location of the Check-box if all didn't work and this has to run on vista and above I Would use [Windows Automation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971513)

Comment: I've tried using spy++ and I did locate the checkbox but for some reason I can't manage to check it.

Answer (score 0):

When the state of a child control changes (in response to a user action), it sends some notification messages to it's parent window, and parent window by catching those messages, performs actions. Those notification messages are `WM_COMMAND` and `WM_NOTIFY`.

By monitoring messages sent to the parent window of your check box control (and checking the control by mouse), I noticed one `WM_COMMAND` message and two `WM_NOTIFY` messages. Those messages where not available when I programmatically sent a `BM_SETCHECK` message to the check box. So the magic revealed.

Sending `WM_NOTIFY` is a little difficult, because you have to allocate memory in the address space of the other process (using `VirtualAllocEx`, for `NMHDR` structure), fill the memory (using `WriteProcessMemory`), send the message, and then release the allocated memory.

Sending `WM_COMMAND` message is too much simpler. I tested it, and it worked!

```
    Win32.SendMessage(SubtitlesSection, Win32.Message.WM_COMMAND, 0, AddSubtitlesCheckbox);
```

The message is sent to the parent control of the check box, using the handle of the control as the fourth parameter. Third parameter of the function should be the control ID, and the ID changes every time. But hopefully it seems that the program checks the control handle and not the ID.