# How to access the menu bar of another application with c#

Tags: c#, winforms, automation

I'm current writing an application that will help automate the installation of various software. This process includes starting another application and then accessing the menu bar to access the open command. I know how to open the application, but can anybody help with how to access the menu bar? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# WinAPI Clicking on menu items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397700/c-sharp-winapi-clicking-on-menu-items)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a special API you can use for that, I believe it's the [Windows Automation API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to send key-strokes to the application, assuming the application uses keyboard shortcuts for its menu options.  For example, in many apps you can use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open the file menu, and then <kbd>S</kbd> to Save or <kbd>X</kbd> to exit, etc.

Comment: One would expect something much better than this coming from someone with 16.9k rep in SO. Im sorry dude, I don't mean to offend you, its just my opinion