# Python Script to open an application & use "Save As" feature

Tags: python

I want to open an application in the system (windows) & then use the "Save As" feature of that application to save the open file with a different extension.

For example:

1. Opening a text file using notepad application & saving the file as csv using the script.
2. Opening a PBIX file using PowerBI application & saving the file as a PBIT / PBIP file.

I tried searching a solution for this as I am a beginner in Python. However couldn't find it. Can somebody help me with this ?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Windows, Mac, other?

Comment: Do you know if all the applications that you want to use have command line interfaces or other APIs? You can open external applications with, e.g., [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run), but then you would just have to interact with/use that application as normal. I expect you can only interact with the application entirely via Python if there is an API/command line interface for all your required instructions.

Comment: For example, notepad has some [limited command line options](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/notepadexe-command-line-options/810760c1-a45a-4013-9544-1c1208e1b389), so to open a file (say a file called `test.txt`) in notepad, you could do: `import subprocess` and then `subprocess.run(["notepad", "/A", "test.txt"])`. This would open the notepad window, but then you'd have to manually save it.

Comment: It seems that there are Python APIs for PowerBI, e.g., https://github.com/andrewvillazon/pbipy. And, if you want to take a text file and save it as CSV, try pandas [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and and [`DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv).

Comment: @jarmod : I am using Windows

Comment: @MattPitkin Thankyou for your response & thankyou for sharing notepad command line options, the PowerBI Python API uses the PowerBI service, however I am trying for the PowerBI Desktop Windows application

Comment: Sounds like you may want to investigate options for automation of Windows applications, example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397700/c-sharp-winapi-clicking-on-menu-items).